# trying to install discord.py onto a raspberry pi, but it's giving me a Remote end closed closed connection without respoonse exception

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

trying to install discord.py onto a raspbery pi 3b, but after running pip to install it, it didn't install, and instead came back with this exception. i would like to know what's going on here so I can fix it.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response```
````

Answer (score 1):

1- Double check the token and try to regenerate the bot token or try to use another bot token

2- Open the browser on the raspberry pi and go to the discord website (this solution always works for me when I use new hosting services)

And I hope it works for you and if nothing works check the network connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is gonna help, but discord works with python 3+, so try `$pip3 install discord.py`?